# Strange problem with vectors

Tags: c++, qt, stl, vector

I have a really strange problem with stl vectors in which the wrong destructor is called for the right object when I call the erase method if that makes any sense.
My code looks something like this:

```
 for(vector<Category>::iterator iter = this->children.begin(); iter != this->children.end(); iter++)
    {
        if((*iter).item == item)
        {
            this->children.erase(iter);
            return;
        }
        -------------------------
    }
```

It's just a simple function that finds the element in the vector which has some item to be searched, and removes said element from the vector. My problem is than when the erase function is called, and thus the object which the iterator is pointing at is being destroyed, the wrong destructor is being called. More specific the destructor of the last element in the vector is being called, and not of the actual object being removed. Thus the memory is being removed from the wrong object, which will still be an element in the vector, and the actual object which is removed from the vector, still has all of it's memory intact.
The costructor of the object looks like this:

```
Category::Category(const Category &from)
{
    this->name = from.name;
    for(vector<Category>::const_iterator iter = from.children.begin(); iter != from.children.end(); iter++)
        this->children.push_back((*iter));

    this->item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
}
```

And the destructor

```
Category::~Category()
{
    this->children.clear();
    if(this->item != NULL)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* parent = this->item->parent();
        if(parent != NULL) parent->removeChild(this->item);
        delete this->item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your copy assignment operator look like?

Comment: A working minimal example would be so much more welcomed.

Comment: I don't have a copy assigment operator, I don't really use it.

Comment: YOU may not use it, but `std::vector` does. I think that may be your problem. You see, `erase` doesn't destroy the object you erase. It copies the successive elements from the the rest of the vector up one, and then it destroys the last one.

Comment: where does the for lop fit into your sequence of operations? At the moment what we see are three separate bits of code with no concept of how they are interlinked. For example, when/where does that for loop get called?

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Comment: Even if the rule of three is followed correctly, this fails because of the mix of pointers and non pointers. Who owns the pointer after the copy assignment? The problem is the same that occurs trying to store `auto_ptr` in a container - it's not possible unless you use a `shared_ptr` to hold the instance of `QTreeWidgetItem`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you erase your element from the vector, each element after it is copied (using the assignment operator) to the previous spot in the vector.  Once this is complete, the last element in the vector is destructed.  This could be why you're seeing your last element get destructed.  Rule number one when using the STL is to ensure the copy semantics for your object are correct.

You should consider writing an assignment operator:

```
Category & operator =(const Category & other);
```

Although this may not be as simple as it sounds, considering objects will be copied and destructed many times in the vector.

Comment: Yes indeed, I had no idea this is how std::vector works. I created the assignment operator and it is indeed called before the destructor. I guess I should switch to a vector of pointers rather than objects.

Comment: be wary, you have a raw pointer, and you need to understand the impact of the copy operations on that pointer, especially given your destructor. Think about this, the vector copies one into another after the erase, and destroys the original, in your current code, the pointer gets deleted (I'm guessing that you can't create a new widget on copy as this is a UI element?) and now your element in the vector is holding on to something that has been deleted...

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use standard algorithms.

The main issue I see is that your destructor for Category asks its parent vector to remove it. That cannot be right, the destructor happens only when the vector is already removing it.

std::vector uses placement-new so will be calling your destructor directly. I do not know what the effect will be to go back to the vector at this point.

Remove the line `if (parent != NULL ) parent->removeChild(this->item)` from the destructor. It is not what you want.

Comment: I had to do a double take on that line too, but actually this is removing one widget from another - which is perfectly acceptable...

Comment: @Nim The issue is that removing an item from a vector will automatically invoke its constructor (you have a vector of objects, not of pointers. Therefore the objects are destructed). Of course if you are erasing "in the middle" it actually does a load of copies but the consequence will be the same, the object with your item gets removed. And then in the destructor you go back to the vector and ask it to remove the item.

Comment: `removeChild()` is part of the *Qt* interface, I don't believe it's the method that is triggering the erase from the vector.

Comment: I was under some impression that removeChild was triggering the first block of code

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. On my implementation (and I am guessing, on yours) when erasing an element from a vector, elements from n+1 to the end  are assigned into it and the very last element is destructed.

Use `std::list` if you don't want this to happen.

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct Category
{
        int item;
        Category(int n=0) : item(n) {}
        ~Category() { std::cout << "Category " << item << " destroyed\n"; }
};
int main()
{
        std::vector<Category> children(3);
        children[0] = Category(0);
        children[1] = Category(1);
        children[2] = Category(2);

        int item = 0;
        std::cout << " beginning the loop \n";
        for( std::vector<Category>::iterator iter = children.begin();
                                       iter != children.end(); ++iter)
        {
            if(iter->item == item)
            {
                    children.erase(iter); //  prints "Category 2 destroyed"!
                    break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << " loop done \n";
} // this will print "Category 1 destroyed" and "Category 2 destroyed"
```

And yes, explicit `erase`/`remove_if` is more readable than the loop.